# Why my PHP loop got broken every time?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, time-limiting

I am a beginner to PHP. I am trying to insert large amount of items into database. I am using `for` loop and `mysqli_query` commands.

My pseudo-code is something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++) {
  mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('$name','$age'); ") ;

}
```

I have my code working a few hundred loops and then poof: **Fatal error**: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds  exceeded in xxx on line xxx

For me, only solution is to manually increment my counter every time after loop breaks.

Is there any other solution? Please, help!

Comment: Check how many records are there and do the math how many you need to insert?

Comment: Define **poof** please?

Comment: (Tip) Don't query whilst in a loop. Create the query within the loop, and execute out of the loop. That'll make it 1 query, rather than 50k.

Comment: First remove semicolon at the end of query and use cron for big process

Comment: Is the script timing out? Try the set_time_limit() function. Calling set_time_limit(0) will remove any time limits for execution of the script.

Comment: Why are you adding the same data to the database 50000 times?!

Comment: remove semicolon from inside mysqli_query

Comment: Add error checking after the query: `mysqli_query($con, "...") or die (mysqli_error($con));`, and tell us the error message.

Comment: Some hosting services have a limit on the number of queries you can do in an hour. You're probably running into it, and the error message would confirm this.

Comment: set_time_limit() function solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Don't do a query for every record one-at-time. You can do multiple inserts with one statement. The example below does 50 at one time. You can probably safely increase that to 100 or even 500.

```
$counter = 0;
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ';
for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++) {
  $counter++;
  $sql .= "('$name','$age'),"; 
  // execute query every 50 records
  if ($counter % 50 === 0) {
      $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
      mysqli_query($con, $query . $sql) ;
      $sql = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw a try catch

```
for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++) {
  try {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('$name','$age'); ") ;
  } catch ($e) {
    // You can log $e here if you want
    // It would also probably be good to print out your query 
    // so you can go back and try it again later
  }

}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` doesn't signal errors, you need to use `or die(mysqli_error($con))` after the call.

Comment: What is `catche`? A typo?

Comment: Yes it should be `catch`

Answer (score 0):

The most helpful answer was the comment from Jay Blanchard:

> Try the `set_time_limit()` function. Calling `set_time_limit(0)` will
>   remove any time limits for execution of the script.

I have inserted set_time_limit(0) at the beginning of the page, and my PHP script now works perfectly!